# How to have Lambda's destination working in SAM

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm trying to figure out how to use the new destination feature, introduced [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/), to transfer data from one SQS queue, to another one, through a Golang lambda.

## Set up

Following AWS documentation, I have build the following SAM template :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  helloworld

Resources:
  helloworldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Timeout: 30
      CodeUri: helloworld/
      Handler: helloworld
      Runtime: go1.x
      Events:
        QueueEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt Tohelloworld.Arn
      Policies:
      - SQSSendMessagePolicy:
          QueueName:
            !GetAtt Fromhelloworld.QueueName

  EventInvokeConfig:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref helloworldFunction
      Qualifier: "$LATEST"
      MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 60
      MaximumRetryAttempts: 0
      DestinationConfig:
        OnSuccess:
          Destination: !GetAtt Fromhelloworld.Arn

  Tohelloworld:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      VisibilityTimeout: 30
  Fromhelloworld:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      VisibilityTimeout: 30
```

I have a trivial golang script, that always succeed :

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(ctx context.Context, name events.SQSEvent) (int, error) {
    return 1, nil
}
func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

Everything is deployed through AWS SAM, ressources are reported to having been correctly created.

## Problem

For each event put in the `ToHelloWorldQueue` I was expecting to get a message with `1` as body in the `FromHelloWorldQueue`.

Through SQS, I manually put an event in the `ToHelloworld` Queue, but the message never reaches the `FromHelloworldQueue`, even if the message has been correctly processed (as reported by CloudWatch). I even tried to manually set the policy to `SQS:*` for this lambda, but the problem still remains.

Can anyone help figuring out why I'm doing wrong please?

## Edit:

### Edit 1:

When directly invoked, the lambda function actually sends the message to the `FromHelloWorld` queue. So this just does not works when the lambda is triggered by the SQS `ToHelloWorld` queue.

Comment: Trying to replicate your findings, I used your code and also built something Python based within the console. With none of those setups I were able to verify the destination working, neither when invoking via SQS nor triggering the lambda manually. How did you verify that the SQS queue received a new message?

Comment: I tried using ```aws sam invoke``` and directly by deploying the code. I finally figured out why this was not working. As stated in the documentation, the destination works when the Lambda is called in a asynchronously way. The ```aws sam invoke``` make an asynchroneous call IF called with an event payload. Otherwise, it's a synchroenous one. When triggered with SQS, the call is synchroneous, hence, the request's result was never forward to the destination queue.

Comment: That is interesting. Could you post the solution you found as the answer to your question? I would particularly be interested why a trigger through SQS is synchronous. I thought we use SQS because it enables asynchronous processing...

Comment: Actually, I don't have any solution yet : as a workaround, I'm manually sending the event to the ```FromHelloWorld``` queue through the sdk. Regarding the Sync/Async stuff (and from my, imperfect, understanding) : since SQS is a Queue, events will still be processing asynchroneously, from the sender perspective, but that does not imply that the lambda is necessarily called asynchroneously, from the queue perspective.

Comment: Hmm, it's unfortunate that you have to replicate what this feature should be for. Your  explanation about sync/async sounds plausible. Let's see what some experimentation and time will show...